# how to click a button in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have this button

```
<button id="stopButton" onClick="stop(); clearInterval(add); ">Sabitle</button>
```

And I have this function

```
function displayMessage(message)
        {
            chatTextArea.value = message + "\n";
            chatTextArea.scrollTop = chatTextArea.scrollHeight;

            if(message == "Stop")
            {
                 !!!!! I want to click stopButton in this area !!!!
            }

        }
```

How can I click this button in function?

Comment: you will have a much easier time if you use jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: $("#stopButton").click()

Comment: I would suggest keeping the html view and js control as separate as possible. AKA having the stopButton call a single function that has the logic for what you need it to do, and use the same funtion in displayMessage().

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("#stopButton")[0].click();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("stopButton").click();
```

Comment: From what I've seen, it is `document.getElementById("stopButton").click();`, not `onclick()`. And this is the only thing that actually works. JQuery (at least my version) simply doesn't work for this.

Comment: Yup. should be click and not onclick. will update that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this in a round-about fashion.

Instead of trying to programmatically click the button, why don't you just call the functions that the button calls when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

$("#stopButton").click();